# JAVA_HOME not working in ubuntu

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, path, java-home

I am new to `ubuntu`. I am trying to use java-8. Where I have already installed java-6 in my `ubuntu` machine. I just want to use java-8 from my terminal (for test purpose); not from all over my machine. 
I want java-6 remains for all other software like eclipse. I heard to to so we can `ubuntu` terminal to export. So I am trying  to do this -

```
$ export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk8
$ export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME
```

after doing this when I type in terminal the fllowing command -

```
$ java -version
```

it gives -

> java version "1.6.0_29" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build
>   1.6.0_29-b11) Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 20.4-b02, mixed mode)

I tried several ways but nothing is working for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are missing the `bin` directory name after the `$JAVA_HOME`. Try this -

```
 $ export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk8
 $ export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

**Note:** I have place the `JAVA_HOME` before `PATH`. That means the `JAVA_HOME/bin` is concatenated with the existing `PATH` where the `JAVA_HOME/bin` is placed at the beginning of the new `PATH`. If you place the `JAVA_HOME/bin` at the end of the current `PATH` then the `JAVA_HOME/bin` is concatenated at the end of the new `PATH`. In this case the older `JAVA_HOME` (if exist one, in your case the jdk-6) may found first at the new `PATH` variable and will get precedence. A lots of times I get wrong when I placed `JAVA_HOME/bin` at the end of the `PATH`. So add `JAVA_HOME/bin` at the beginning in this case.